# Powershell memory error , groupmembership

Tags: powershell

Could any please propose a better solution to export group membership based on filter .
Everytime when I execute below script I get memory error although I have implemented filter but It's very difficult to filter base on L1, L2 userid because there are more than 30000 users.

Also one more error I am getting while executing `"Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity powershell"`.

ForEach-Object : `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

My requirement to export group membership is in below format only.It's extremely slow , take 4-5 hours to export even after filter used.

My code:

```
$FilePath = "c:/Data/L_Accounts_Group_Membership_L1-L2.csv"
$OuDomain = "OU=test,OU=abc,OU=com1,DC=com2,DC=com3,DC=com4"
$users = Get-QADUser -SamAccountName [L1-L2]* -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0
$users | Sort-Object SamAccountName | % {
    $user = $_ | Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName
    if ($lastDomain -eq $user.dn) {
        $lastDomain = ""
    } else {
        $lastDomain = $user.dn
    }
    $groups = Get-QADMemberOf $_ | Select-Object -expandProperty Name
    $groups | % {
        $user2 = New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
                "Domain" = $lastDomain
                "sAMAccountName" = $user.sAMAccountName
                "Group" = $_
            }
        $user2
    }
} | export-csv $FilePath
```

Comment: what are L1 L2? And [L1-L2]* what is filtering?

Comment: L1 and L2 are user_id prefix , like L100394 , L200494

Comment: Why do you store the distinguished name of the user as "Domain"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parameter `-DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties` for the Get-QADUser cmdlet. It reduces the data retrieved from active directory.

Consider to skip the sorting. This seems always to slow down scripts. I can't see the reason for sorting in your script anyways.

Instead of "saving" the users in a variable you should handle the objects directly (if you don't need the $users anymore later in the script).

```
Get-QADUser -SamAccountName [L1-L2]* -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties | % {...
```

The QADUser-Object has two properties called *"MemberOf"* and *"NestedMemberOf"*. Those properties contain the distinguished name of the groups the user is member of(direct and indirect). Those are string properties and thus much faster to handle than an array of objects returned from a cmdlet. I assume you won't be needing "NestedMemberOf" though because you did not use the parameter `-Indirect` for the Get-QADMemberOf cmdlet.

```
$result = $users | % {
    $SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
    if ($lastDomain -eq $_.dn) {
        $lastDomain = ""
    } else {
        $lastDomain = $_.dn
    }

    $_.MemberOf | % {
        $user = New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
                "Domain" = $lastDomain
                "SamAccountName" = $SamAccountName
                "Group" = $_
            }
        $user
    }
}

$result | sort-object SamAccountName | Export-CSV $FilePath
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the reply, I have executed the script and it's still running from last 30 mins, actually this script is a part of another script , I am sorting users because later on I am comparing those values with Oracle database , both user id exists in oracle as well as AD and because of this we are facing sync issues. That's why I wanted to export user_id in this format only so that it would be easy to compare. I will feedback further.

Comment: I used the above recommendation but nothing works. Please have a look to this link . Thanks. http://pastebin.com/See8S9cm

Comment: @Naveenk Which version of the Quest cmdlets do you use? I recall one verion was a memory hog. I can see you still use the Get-QADMemberOf cmdlet(because this one throws the exeptions). Try to use the property "memberOf" from the user-object. You could modify this line `$user = $_ | Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName, memberOf`. You'd be able to access the groupmemberships with `$user.memberOf`

Comment: ActiveRoles Management Shell 1.5.1, a part of Quest ActiveRoles Server 6.7

Comment: @Naveenk Could you post the code you have at this moment? It's difficult to help you further without knowing what changes you implemented. Also see my edits in my post above. Sorting the result is better than in sorting the middle of the code.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks a lot, it's extremely fast. I am able to export all users using above script.

Answer (score 0):

For avoid `'System.OutOfMemoryException'`  error you need to execute the script querying less user at a time.

[L1-L2]* have astrange behaviour in `get-qaduser`, execute your script first time with L1* and after with L2*. If  it is not enough you need more filter: L0*, then L10*, then L11*, then L12*, and so on.

For debug the `"Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity powershell"`  error you need to know the value passed to `Get-qadmemberof` at the moment of the error, probably doens't exist.

Comment: but there are n number of users , and after than I need to compare those groupmembership with oracle ,where I can export same values in oracle without any error using powershell. I connect oracle through powershell and query database.